# Join or Multiple Query for Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Consider small facebook like app.
Given a list of post-id,the sql has to extract all likes for the post and user who liked it.

```
Like
-post_id
-user_id

User
-user_id
-and many more columns(around 9)
```

**As the 'Like' table will be huge** which is a better solution?

A)

```
result=SELECT * FROM Like WHERE post_id in (post_id_list).
user_list=extract_user_id_from_result
user=SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id in (user_list)
```

B)

```
SELECT user.* FROM User JOIN Like on(Like.user_id=User.user_id) 
WHERE Like.post_id in (post_list)
```

Comment: The data which I have now is not large enough to see the difference.I am making the app and enthusisatic to know

Answer (score 0):

as I know, inner join is a kind of Cartesian, and it dose not good performance. so try to use sub query, its better I think.